# .NET Application pool often overflowing

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory

.NET application pool often overflowing. What Should I do for solving this problem?
I am using singletton class for db connection. Also; My all db connection lines in using code block. So, it be dispose by .NET engine.

What Should I do for solving this problem?

Comment: Didn't you mean 'connection pool'?

Comment: Post the code of your singletton class. There might be an error in it.

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly use perfmon to moniter .NET CLR variables like allocated memory etc. This is generally a very good indicator for finding issues with any .NET process.
- If these indicate an issue, use tools like windbg to debug and find where the exception has occured.
- Also like Sardez mentioned above, properly dispose all objects that are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make the application pool bigger?! 
What else runs in the pool?

Comment: There isnt another application in this pool. How to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure objects are properly disposed. Create a mechanism than holds initialized objects and make suze they were disposed after the object is closed.

Comment: But, I am using singletton class for all db connections. And, I am writing all code in using blocks. When write in using block; system automaticly dispose, after processing. isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

could you expand on what you are trying to achieve with the singleton, you may not need it if you are using connection pooling in your connection string..?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28VS.80%29.aspx

http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/040830.htm

Answer (score 0):

> Singleton class for db connection

Does this mean that you only ever **have one** connection or that the singleton is responsible for creating the connection(s)?

If you just have the one connection, then there is your problem.